# How to deal with users posting religious threats?

Tags: support, flags

Just a few minutes ago, a particular user created two accounts and posted threatening posts against a certain religion. In such cases, what should be the action taken because the user can just keep creating accounts and keep posting such things because flagging is not going to help either.

Here is a fully censored snapshot of a particular who just happened to do that.

[image: Snap]

Comment: Flag like you would flag any other crap.

Comment: IMO, just flag as offensive. We as a community have a near-limitless supply of flags.

Comment: As some point he'll get tired of this and crawl back to his den. No need to worry.

Comment: There are more hardcore things mods can do (or ask devs to do) for multi-user troublesome users (e.g. ip bans). Just keep flagging and it'll get sorted out

Comment: michaelb958,@Bart - If the user is going to keep creating new accounts, flagging won't actually help right?

Comment: @RichardTingle - I guess IP ban won't work if the user is using a proxy or something.

Comment: Sure it will. There are people behind the scenes who pay attention to situations like this. You could even opt for the occasional "other" flag and explain what you're seeing. This is not the first user, it won't be the last. But they are handled just fine.

Comment: Could you post image of full post ?

Comment: @Won't: I think you meant "Jews-y". *hides from pun police*

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Just flag it. It's from a known individual that likes to upset people, and they occasionally fixate on us from time to time.

Flag -> offensive or spam -> be done with it. Don't mention them, don't give them any indication that they've upset you, don't leave any comments - radio silence and flags is the best course of action.

As you do this, the system will make it increasingly difficult for them to persist.

Comment: Does the system deal with multiple accounts and proxy situations? Just wanna know.

Comment: @Ɍ.Ɉ - it does. I won't go into specifics, but this user is being blocked, despite using Tor.

Comment: @Ɍ.Ɉ This isn't spam.  Don't flag non-spam posts as spam.  This is offensive; flag it accordingly.

Comment: Geo-locate them from their IP address, then nuke them from orbit... it's the only way to be sure.

Comment: @Bohemian - collateral damage be damned?

Comment: @Oded How is taking out the entire Indian Hacker Team "collateral damage"?

Comment: @TimPost Do you guys file case\complain\FIR for that ? I love to see those dumb people behind the bars

Comment: @michaelb958 - The scenario I had in mind: "geo location: Gaza city. Initiate nuke from orbit. There goes Jerusalem. Whoops.".